# 6502 Assembly convert a 2 digit number to 4 digit

Tags: assembly, 6502

I have a random number(from 0 to 31) x stored at address `$00`, and another random number(from 0 to 31) y stored at address `$01`. I want to use these two numbers as coordinates and derive an address `$xy`. For example if x = 2, y = 10, the address would be `$020a`. I'm a beginner, so could someone share an effective way of doing this?

I want to store some other value in the derived address `$020a`, so this is why I need it.

Comment: What is the actual question?   You have the x and y coord in 00 and 01.   Job done?   What's next?   Read the x and y coord and do what you are supposed to do with them....?

Comment: Yes, much clearer now. The address would be $020a with x=2 and y=10 right?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to use 020b as an address into memory, is that what you mean?  (I'm asking because your reference to "x" and "y" makes it sound like some sort of coordinate address).   Is it the case that you want to access the data at address 0x020b?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Yes. Because the easy 6502 simulator(http://skilldrick.github.io/easy6502/) draws a pixel whenever it encounters a `STA` command. If the command is `STA $020b`, it draws the pixel at the point (2,10). Given x = 2, y = 10, I want to get the address `$020b` so that I know where to draw that pixel.

Comment: @Meteorite You should change your address from $020b to $020a so you don't throw off people reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use indirect addressing. Indirect addressing takes an address plus the Y register, so make sure you clear the Y register first.

```
LDY #0
LDA ($0),Y
```

To store at that address:

```
LDA #$FF ; or whatever you want to store
LDY #0
STA ($0),Y
```

Here is some more info on indirect addressing: http://www.obelisk.demon.co.uk/6502/addressing.html#IDY

I am rusty but hopefully this steers you in the proper direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
LDY #$00
LDA #VALUE
STA ($00),Y
```

This loads the data into the accumulator from the address contained in $00 and $01 as described in your question.

When address $00 has 10 or $0a, and address $01 has 2 or $2 this will write the VALUE to address $02a.

This uses the Indirect Indexed Addressing described in http://www.dwheeler.com/6502/oneelkruns/asm1step.html

Comment: Bringing back old Commodore 64 memories. Oh the joy.

Comment: Haha. It is indeed so much fun learning the 6502 assembly language.

Comment: Curious what you are using 6502 assembly language for?

Comment: Atari 800XL represent!

Comment: I'm taking a class that deals with some vintage CPUs(6502, X86, ...), and we are also learning 4 corresponding languages. This is part of the class project. I used a empty memory to store the address in the first place, but it sometimes trashes the memory.

Comment: Cool.. it is great to do some assembly language with these "simpler" CPUs, it really helps to better understand how powerful the complex CPUs of today really work.